# Spin Control not working

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm using spin control in MFC, C++ to change the value for the number.

here is my code:

```
void CHello_worldDlg::OnDeltaposSpin1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMUPDOWN pNMUpDown = reinterpret_cast<LPNMUPDOWN>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    m_fSpinIncrement = m_fScalingFactor;
    if(pNMUpDown->iDelta == -1) // Increment the value
    {
    IncrementData(m_fSpinIncrement);
    }
    else // Decrement the value
    {
    DecrementData(m_fSpinIncrement);
    }
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_TEXT3, IDC_SPIN1);
    *pResult = 0;
}
```

is there any error inside? and the number change will be at another static textbox~

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're doing too much work. Everything you're trying to do can be done better by simply setting the appropriate [properties of the spin control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd91377e%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

1. [`Auto Buddy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276380%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) connects the spin control to the edit box preceding it.
2. `Set Buddy Integer` makes the edit box handle integers automatically.
3. `Alignment` set to 'Right' will make the spin control neatly dock against the edit box.

The only code you need is calling `SetRange()` in the OnInitDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Did you call the `SpinButtonCtrl::SetRange()` method in any part of your code? From your code, I don't think it is getting the range you want.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain more on how is the spin control not working? Do you mean it is not increasing or decreasing the number at all?

Comment: When i pressed the arrow up/down button, the textbox value is not increasing/decreasing. thanks

Comment: you did return the value to update the value after increment or decrement.

Comment: but the numbers inside my textbox remains as'0'

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo there, i meant *didnt

Comment: How should i update the value? as the value has to be displayed at the static text?

Comment: You can use CSpinButtonCtrl::GetPos()

Comment: int GetPos() const;
This member function returns the value of the spin control at the time the member function is called.